# Ant wsimport task failing

Tags: ant, jax-ws, java-6, wsimport

I have a simple ant script to build my classes from a sdl. Unfortunately wsimport fails immediately. I suspect it has something to do with classpaths.

```
<taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${jaxws.lib.dir}/jaxws-tools.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<wsimport
    wsdl="${project.wsdl.dir}\some.wsdl"
    destdir="${jaxws.output.dir}"
    keep="false"
    extension="true"
    verbose="true"
    wsdlLocation="http://localhost/wsdl"
    target="2.1">
    <depends file="${project.wsdl.dir}"/>
    <produces dir="${jaxws.output.dir}"/>
</wsimport>
```

The this is the output it produces:

> [wsimport] 15 Mar 2013 12:23:25 PM com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory createDocumentBuilderFactory
>   [wsimport] SEVERE: null
>   [wsimport] java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.createDocumentBuilderFactory(XmlFactory.java:176)
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.(DOMForest.java:162)
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.resetSchema(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:215)
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:114)
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.XJC.createSchemaCompiler(XJC.java:72)
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.(WsimportOptions.java:152)
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.(WsimportTool.java:89)
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.(WsimportTool.java:92)
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport2.execute(WsImport2.java:848)
>   [wsimport]     at com.sun.istack.tools.ProtectedTask.execute(ProtectedTask.java:103)
>   [wsimport]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:269)
>   [wsimport]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
>   [wsimport]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:301)
>   [wsimport]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:135)
>   [wsimport]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.parseBuildFile(InternalAntRunner.java:192)
>   [wsimport]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:401)
>   [wsimport]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)

If I run the commandline create by the verbose logging, on wsimport, from the jax-ws bin directory everything works perfectly

```
[wsimport] command line: wsimport -d C:\Development\Source\ccs\jaxws-output -extension -verbose -target 2.1 C:\Development\Source\ccs\wsdl\some.wsdl -wsdllocation http://localhost/wsdl
```

I tried looking for a solution, but right now I am out of ideas

Comment: this means it is an ant specific issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that one of the things tedious to use in the approach that you mention (`taskdef` and `wsimport`) is adding environment variables, especially when you want to use SSL and Basic authentication in your web service. I another hand, you can use the `wsimport` tool without define a new task. Something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>
<project name="generate-client" default="main" basedir=".">
    <property name="java.home" 
        value="X:\Software\jdk1.7.0_11" />
    <property name="wsdl.location" 
        value="http://localhost/wsdl" />
    <target name="main">
        <exec executable="${java.home}\bin\wsimport.exe">
            <arg line="${wsdl.location} -s src -Xdebug -verbose -Xnocompile" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Now that you have an idea, you can customize the output directory, add the target version ...

Comment: I actually wanted to avoid this approach so that builds can be platform independent. But if this is the suggested way,I'll do it

Comment: Builds can be semi-platform-independent if you use `<exec ... osfamily="">` several times, one for each family you intend to support.